# AngularJS Jasmine Testing - How to Test AJAX Function That is Called on Controller Load

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a controller that looks like:

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, myService){

    $scope.myFunction = function(){
        myService.myAJAXCall().then(function(data){
            $scope.myVariable = data;
        }, function(){
            console.log('failed call');
        });
    };
    $scope.myFunction();

    $scope.$watch('myVariable', function(newValue){
        if(newValue === 'something'){
             $scope.test = true;
        }
        else{
             $scope.test = false;
        }
    });

});
```

`$scope.myFunction()` makes a AJAX call to an endpoint and sets `$scope.myVariable` with the value returned.  I call `$scope.myFunction()` on page load.

I'd like to test the watch on `$scope.myVariable`.  I can do this successfully if I don't call `$scope.myFunction()` on controller load with:

```
describe('myTest', function(){
    it('should test $scope.test', function(){
        scope.test = false;
        scope.myVariable = 'something';
        scope.$apply();
        expect(scope.test).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

But this doesn't work if I call `$scope.myFunction()` on page load.  The `scope.myVariable = 'something';` declaration is always overwritten by the AJAX call made with `myService.myAJAXCall()`.

How should I write my test so that it doesn't run into this conflict if I call `$scope.myFunction()` on controller load?

Comment: Are you not mocking `myService` ? Also after controller instantiation make a $scope.$apply() call right there so that ajax promise will gets resolved and hen continue your test as is and should be fine.. Can you show your test setup

Comment: @PSL `myService` is being mocked, but instead of testing against the values returned from the mock, I'd like to test the values against the explicit values I set for `scope.myVariable` within the `it` callback.  Can you be more specific as to where to put the `$scope.$apply` when you say 'right there'?

Comment: Right after your controller creation for your test... Can you show your test setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key was to manually run a digest cycle during test suite set-up using `scope.$apply()`.  This flushed out my AJAX call, which allowed me to test the `$watch`.

```
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $controller('myController', {
        $scope: scope,
        myService: myService
    });
    // Apply the digest cycle manually at initialization of test suite
    scope.$apply();
}));
```